# How to Creating New file with Crontab with detail?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cron

I was planning to using the Cron to create multiple file separate by date. However the code I'm using did not produce any file. This the code I'm currently using.

`* * * * * touch /home/tect/Desktop/Try$(date +%Y%m%d-%H%M%S).txt 2>/tmp/foo.log`

PS:The Cron & System Log did not show any rejection and the foo.log  also did not show any error.

Please assist me to point out the fail in my code.Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is quite old question, but it could be ususeful for someone who will get there.

As suggested [here](https://superuser.com/a/1158296/895926) it could be problem with not having new line at the end of file

Answer (score 0):

The way cron executes a bit more complex commands is a bit cumbersome (different shell, path, etc. - see `/etc/crontab` for your setup).
In my opinion it is better to create a wrapper script, using your example:

`#!/bin/bash
touch ${HOME}/Try$(date +%Y%m%d-%H%M%S).txt`

Make sure it's executable: `chmod u+x cronscript.sh`
And run the script from crontab:

```
* * * * * ${HOME}/cronscript.sh >> ${HOME}/foo.log 2>&1
```